# Spring dynamic object inject - @Autowired

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

imagine one dao class and one service(BO) class . how to automatically inject FwObject  to setFwObject method , because FwObject having user related information and these piece of code should be written  inside framework

```
Class MyAction exdends ActionSupport{
     @Autowired
     private SomeService someService;

     @Autowired
     FwBean fwObj;  

     execute(){
          fwObj.set(fromRequest()); //build this object using request  and session values 
     }     
}   


@Service
class PersonServiceImpl {        
    @Autowired
    private SomeDAO someDao;            
}



@Repository
    class PersonDAO {
      @Autowired
      public void setFwBean(FwBean obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
        this.fwObject = obj  //object  will be come from MyAction
     }   
 }
```

```
         <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

    </web-app>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- scans the classpath for annotated components (including @Repostory 
    and @Service  that will be auto-registered as Spring beans  -->      
     <bean id="fwBean" class="com.sriseshaa.fw.helper.FwBean" scope="request">

          <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean -->
          <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sriseshaa" />

    <!-- methods or classes needing to run in a complete transaction will
    be annotated with Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Creates a data source that can provide a connection to in-memory embedded database populated 
    with test data
    see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch12s08.html   -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"  >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/fwtest" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


    <!-- This will ensure that hibernate or jpa exceptions are automatically translated into
         Spring's generic DataAccessException hierarchy for those classes annotated with Repository
         For example see PersonDaoJpa-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:persistenceXmlLocation="META-INF/persistence.xml" 
          p:persistenceUnitName="springJpaPersistenceUnit" />          


    <!-- bean post-processor for JPA annotations -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <!-- Transaction Config -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <!-- use declarative transaction management  -->
    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>




 </beans>
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fwBean': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fwBean': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:653)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:604)
    at com.sriseshaa.fw.helper.FwBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$79187402.toString(<generated>)
    at com.sriseshaa.fw.helper.dao.AbstractDAO.setFwObject(AbstractDAO.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    ... 36 more
```

how to set **request level scope** for FwBean, because carefully we have to create new FwBean instance for every request or **every request having own FwBean instance**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is. Why not autowire `SomeDao` as well?

Comment: how to inject FwObject to setFwObject method  using with annotations

Comment: @Arun you still have the issue ? Eveything seems to be correct here . Remove the duplicate <tx:annotation-driven /> once . Rest all seems fine .

Comment: @Aravind still have the same issue !

Comment: @Arun also cross check the FwBean configuration . I hope you don't have an '@Component' there since you're doing a component scan of com.sriseshaa package . I don't think you have one else you might have ended up with a duplicate bean issue . but crosscheck it .

Comment: @Aravind issue solved! The problem was inside the setter method.  i tried to  invoke the  fwbean.toString() method. after removing that line it is working fine

Comment: @Arun Cool - glad you resolved it :)

Comment: @AravindA thanks for your precious time and support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the injection to work , FwObject  should be a spring bean . If you want to follow the factory pattern , Spring supports it using the [factory-method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) attribute in your beans .

```
@Repository
   class SomeDAO {
     @Autowired
     public void setFwObject(FwObject obj) {
     this.fwObject = obj
   }   
 }
```

should autowire FwObject  if it's a Spring bean . Else use getAutowireCapableBeanFactory() and use the autowire method .

For the request not active error , 
You try using

```
   <aop:scoped-proxy/>
```

as defined in the reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.3/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection)

```
If you want to inject a (for example) HTTP request scoped bean into another bean, you 
will need to inject an AOP proxy in place of the scoped bean. That is, you need to 
inject a proxy object that exposes the same public interface as the scoped object, but 
that is smart enough to be able to retrieve the real, target object from the relevant
scope (for example a HTTP request) and delegate method calls onto the real object.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inside the setter method. i tried to invoke the fwbean.toString() method. after removing that line ( **// System.out.println(obj)**; ) it is working fine

```
@Repository
    class PersonDAO {
      @Autowired
      public void setFwBean(FwBean obj) {
       // System.out.println(obj);  defect line
        this.fwObject = obj  //object  will be come from MyAction
     }   
 }
```